# Can't connect to a Flask application from inside an container

Tags: docker, flask

I have a flask application running in a Dev Container by running the following command:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 --debug
```

And the application runs fine on the browser by accessing `http://localhost:3000`, however when trying to access through the internal ip that my docker has (http://172.17.0.1:3000) while inside **another** container I cannot access at all.

I am guessing that flask is not binding truly to 0.0.0.0 since I can't access the application through my local ip (192.168.1.20) and through docker's ip (172.17.0.1).

The output while starting the debug server is:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 --debug
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:3000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are all but useless, and you never need to look them up.  How are you starting the two containers?  (Do they share a Docker network, maybe by virtue of being in the same Compose file?)

Comment: One is started through docker-compose and the other was started using vscode's dev container function.

Comment: Most likely they are in different docker networks then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the Dev container generated by vscode to my other container's network by adding the following to my `devcontainer.json`:

```
"runArgs": [
        "--network=supre_default",
        "--name=forecast_python"
    ]
```

Now I can connect to the Devcontainer inside another container using `curl http://forecast_python:3000`